# How to create ModelForm for separate databases?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have two databases:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'data_base_1',                  
        'USER': 'root',                       
        'PASSWORD': 'password',               
        'HOST': '',                           
        'PORT': '',                  
    },
    'another_database': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'data_base_2',               
        'USER': 'root',                  
        'PASSWORD': 'password',           
        'HOST': '',                       
        'PORT': '',                       
    },
}
```

How should I create ModelForms for 'default' models and for 'another_database' models?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by creating ModelForms **FOR** one or another?

You can create ModelForms as usual and use

```
obj.save(using='another_database')
```

in order to save the data in a specific DB, if this was actually your question:)

See [Selecting a database for save()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save)